# How to select the right index tool for LuaLaTeX in 2019?

Tags: luatex, indexing, xindy, makeindex, xindex

There are several tools for indexing:

- [luaindex](https://ctan.org/pkg/luaindex) (one release from 2011, written in Lua, "This is an alpha version!", by Markus Kohm)
- [makeindex](https://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) (1987-1993, written in C, by L. Lamport, P. Chen et al.)
- [xindy](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindy) (last release 2013, written in CLISP, by J. Schrod)
- [xindex](https://ctan.org/pkg/xindex) (several releases in 2019, written in Lua, UTF-8 support but compatible with makeindex, by Herbert Voß)
- and many more

What should a user keep in mind when selecting the right index tool for an UTF-8 lualatex document in 2019?

Comment: `xindex`...write in `Lua`

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Added xindex to the list. Thank you.

Comment: I basically never create indices, so I'm not really qualified to answer. But some remarks: I think `luaindex` is conceptually great, but it han't been updated for 8 years and isn't compatible with current luatex versions. Also a look at it's source code suggests that it might be quite slow. For non-trivial amounts of entries `xindex` is also very slow, but that is easy to fix if you don't mind some Lua programming. Anyway while xindex is written in Lua, it is still called as an external program, so it is more similar to xindy than to luaindex.

Comment: Also AFAICT no system currently uses Unicode collations, so for non-english text the sorting can often lead to problems. So currently I would try xindy, mostly because I trust their sorting system the most.

Comment: Just as an aside. Even with `luatex` I'm still relying on `makeindex`, with the sort key generated from within TeX. I believe the sorting rules should be applied (in most cases) in the context where the term to be indexed appears. To automate it I wrote a package (`esindex`), which does most of the work.

Comment: I need an example regarding the use of Xindex, can anyone provide a MWE?? Since I am using lots of Unicode fonts in my project

Comment: @MarcelKrüger With `imakeidx`, the index comes out in Unicode order (under xelatex). `\newpage
व्यंजन\index{व्यंजन}
\newpage
ʣʤʥ\index{ʣʤʥ}
\newpage
qwerty\index{qwerty}
\newpage
санскрита\index{санскрита}
\newpage
\index{}
\newpage
\index{}
\newpage
១២៣៤៥\index{១២៣៤៥}`. I must try some experiments.

Comment: Also `upmendex`: https://ctan.org/pkg/upmendex